# Performance issue when using count (*) on a view

Tags: sql-server, database, count, sql-server-2016, database-performance

We have an SQL view 'xyz' that is currently generating 26 thousands records in 16 seconds, when the below statement is executed:

```
Select * from xyz ----executes in 16 seconds
```

But when a `count(*)` is added, the statement kept on executing for 4 hours until I manually cancelled the query:

```
Select count(*) from xyz ----executes for 4 hours until cancelled
```

I don't see any blocker in the activity monitor for the select count(*) statement. Not sure why `count(*)` is causing performance issues.

Comment: Need to see the query behind the xyz view

Comment: Generate the execution plans for each query and compare them. SSMS has great visualisations for execution plans, and this website is great for sharing them; https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/